Lazy-init property is unexpectedly accessed when using xUnit and AutoFixture
Suppose I have the following class (which is a minimal repro of my actual problem):
public class InitOnce<T>
    where T : struct
{
    private T? _value;

    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public T Value => _value ??= DefaultValue;
}

Using xUnit and AutoFixture, I'd like to write a unit test that verifies the following:

The first time Value is accessed, it's initialized to the current value of DefaultValue.
Any subsequent changes to DefaultValue are ignored.

That is, the following test code should pass:
private static void RunTest(InitOnce<int> initOnce)
{
    initOnce.DefaultValue = 1;
    Assert.Equal(1, initOnce.Value);
    initOnce.DefaultValue = 2;
    Assert.Equal(1, initOnce.Value);
}

If I explicitly create InitOnly within the test body, then the test passes:
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void Test1(IFixture fixture)
{
    InitOnce<int> initOnce = fixture.Build<InitOnce<int>>().OmitAutoProperties().Create();
    RunTest(initOnce); // PASS
}

I'd like to eliminate the boilerplate setup code and inject the InitOnce instance:
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void Test2([NoAutoProperties] InitOnce<int> initOnce)
{
    RunTest(initOnce); // FAIL - why?
}

But Test2 unexpectedly fails with the following error, whether it's run with the Visual Studio Test Explorer or dotnet test:

Assert.Equal() Failure: Values differ
Expected: 1
Actual:   0

Apparently, something accesses the Value property before RunTest changes DefaultValue from 0 to 1. Why does this happen, and how can I get Test2 to pass?
I'm targeting .NET 8.0, and I'm using the latest versions of these packages:
<PackageReference Include="AutoFixture.Xunit2" Version="4.18.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.9.2" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="3.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>


why are you even using AutoFixture and not instantiate an instance by yourself to test the behavior?

@IvanPetrov: As I stated at the outset, this is a minimal repro of the problem. I'm using AutoFixture because in my actual scenario, the SUT participates in dependency injection and has numerous dependencies, most of which are irrelevant to the test.

so the question is more like - why does fixture.Build<InitOnce<int>>().OmitAutoProperties().Create(); differ from using argument injection with attribute [NoAutoProperties] InitOnce<int> initOnce

Right. For this simple example, the former is of course equivalent to new InitOnly<int>(), but I wanted to highlight that Test1 and Test2 differ only in the use of argument injection.

Could it be an init only value? If that's the case you could use record class with  T args?
